# Почему не обновляются данные в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Форма:

```
<?php   // файл: edit_php.php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php WHERE id=$id",$db);
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        printf('
        <h1>Редагування статті <i><u>%s</u></i></h1>
        <div class="edit_article">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post">
        <p>Назва:<br><input class="php_name" type="text" name="name" value="%s"></p>
        <p><textarea name="text">%s</textarea></p>
        <p>Опис(для статті):<br><textarea name="description">%s</textarea></p>
        <center><h3>SEO-налаштування</h3></center>
        <p>Опис:<br><textarea>%s</textarea></p>
        <p>Ключові слова(через кому):<br><input class="php_name" name="meta_k" value="%s"></p>
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="%s">
        <p><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_php" value="Змінити"></p>

        </form>
        </div>',$myrow['name'],$myrow['name'],$myrow['text'],$myrow['description'],$myrow['meta_d'],$myrow['meta_k'],$id);
    }
```

Обработчик:

```
<?php    // файл edit.php:
include('../../db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit_php'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $meta_d = $_POST['meta_d'];
    $meta_k = $_POST['meta_k'];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `php` SET `name`='$name', `text`='$text', `description`='$description', `meta_d`='$meta_d', `meta_k`='$meta_k'");
}
```

Почему данные в MySQL не вставляются?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть такие поля!!! А оно пишет што не

Comment: Какие ошибки? Присылается ли `$_POST['submit_php']`? И забудь уже наконец про `mysql_query`, используйте [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: а вы не забыли в update что-нить типа where id=$id ?

Comment: прежде чем использовать запрос в коде, вы можете его проверить выполнив на прямую, если запрос работает правильно, то дальше уже смотреть что приходит в посте, и каков конечный запрос, его вид

Comment: все пост хорошо отправлени а от што то с запросом

Comment: Предоставьте вывод функции mysql_error(), запрос составленный Вами некорректный, нету конкатенции строк, он скорее всего не понимает что Вы за ересь ему передаёте в запись, идём далее где слово WHERE, он не понимает что ему редактировать. И проверьте что у Вас в переменных типа $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE `php` SET `name`='".$name."', `text`='".$text."', `description`='".$description."', `meta_d`='".$meta_d."', `meta_k`='".$meta_k."'"); - вот так должно работать...у тебя переменные внутри строки не парсяться...ну и наверное апдейтить надо конкретную строку - надо добавить идентификатор строки...лучше всего єхните запрос и попробуйте его віполнить через myadmin

Comment: не работает. Может ето от textarea

Comment: $query = mysql_query("UPDATE php SET name='".$name."', text='".$text."', description='".$description."', meta_d='".$meta_d."', meta_k='".$meta_k."' WHERE id='".$id."'"); нету ж явного указания что именно менять...вкидывайте в запрос какой-то идентификатор как в условии where...

Comment: Та я where добавил "UPDATE php SET name='".$name."', text='".$text."', description='".$description."', meta_d='".$meta_d."', meta_k='".$meta_k."'.WHERE id='".$id."'"

Comment: echo "UPDATE php SET name='".$name."', text='".$text."', description='".$description."', meta_d='".$meta_d."', meta_k='".$meta_k."' WHERE id='".$id."'"; что вывело на экран?

Comment: UPDATE php SET name='Урок1. Вступ', text=' потом текст из форми потом ', description=' потом текст а потом уже ', meta_d='', meta_k='PHP dfghgfrdfgfd edrfg' WHERE id='1'

Comment: попробуй теперь его в myadmin исполнить, сразу напишет в чем проблема...

Comment: Чот не  понял! Можно подробнее

Comment: если есть доступ к myadmin то зайдите в панель далле ищите вкладку sql там в поле введите запрос и нажмите исполнить - если запрос правилен то он исполнится, иначе - выдост ошибку с описанием проблемы...

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '$name' in 'field list'

Comment: значит в таблице нету такого поля...

Comment: зара кину фото в ответи

Comment: кинь тогда полную версию запроса сюда